# Unable To Add Custom Fonts To iOS 4.3

Tags: ios4, custom-font

I know this Question has been asked several times before, and I have tried all the steps mentioned but still it does not work for me :(

I have font file name "spyv3b.ttf". I added it to my project, added its name in info.plist file as "spyv3b.ttf". Also it is copied to Bundle Resource. I installed this font in font book and there it is named as "Spylord Bold". I checked in my project by:

`NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont FontWithName:@"Spylord Bold" size:22]);`

it is returning null. Can anyone tell me where can I be mistaken? Thanks a lot in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very weird problem - the one i guess no one will ever have.... My every step from start to end was OK.The problem was due to the presence of two **app-Info.plist** files...! I don't know when did I added the second one. After deletion of one plist file, when i still didn't made it, I created new project, added my previous project files to it and repeated all the steps for adding custom fonts.

Now everything is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy but little tricky one. Follow the listed steps:

- Add fonts .ttf files int your project under the head of "Resources"
- Add all the font details in your project info.plist file.
- Check your required font is available in Xcode font family with NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont familyNames]);

### Output on console:

2012-08-12 07:49:27.278 Quiz[1134:c07] (
    Thonburi,
    "Snell Roundhand",
    "Academy Engraved LET",
    "Marker Felt",
    "Geeza Pro",
    "Arial Rounded MT Bold",
    "Trebuchet MS",
    Arial,
    Marion,
    "Gurmukhi MN",
    "Malayalam Sangam MN",
    "Bradley Hand",
    "Kannada Sangam MN",
    "Bodoni 72 Oldstyle",
    Cochin,
    "Sinhala Sangam MN",
    "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN",
    Tahoma,
    Papyrus,
    Verdana,
    "Zapf Dingbats",
    Courier,
    "Hoefler Text",
    "Euphemia UCAS",
    Helvetica,
    "Hiragino Mincho ProN",
    "Bodoni Ornaments",
    "Apple Color Emoji",
    Optima,
    "Gujarati Sangam MN",
    "Devanagari Sangam MN",
    "Times New Roman",
    Kailasa,
    "Telugu Sangam MN",
    "Heiti SC",
    Futura,
    "Bodoni 72",
    Baskerville,
    "Chalkboard SE",
    "Heiti TC",
    Copperplate,
    "Party LET",
    "American Typewriter",
    AppleGothic,
    "Bangla Sangam MN",
    Noteworthy,
    Zapfino,
    "Tamil Sangam MN",
    "DB LCD Temp",
    "Arial Hebrew",
    Chalkduster,
    Georgia,
    "Helvetica Neue",
    "Gill Sans",
    Palatino,
    "Courier New",
    "Oriya Sangam MN",
    Didot,
    "Bodoni 72 Smallcaps"
)

---

- Check the exact name of your font in the font-family with NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Tahoma"]);

### Output on console:

2012-08-12 07:49:27.280 Quiz[1134:c07] (
    "Tahoma-Bold"
)

---

- Use the font with the name shown after NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Tahoma"]);
- lblQuizName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Tahoma-Bold" size:64.0];

### Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my font name didn't appeared in `NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont familyNames]);` but it is installed in font book. And also I can see my custom font name in nib file, but it is not applying.